# Authentification with the Flickr API without having to click on a link

Tags: api, authentication, server-side, flickr

In a website I'm working on, I must use  the Flickr API to access the private data of my client.
In fact, I just need to call flickr.tags.getListUserRaw, but unfortunately, it seems like auth is required for that. What I want to do is authenticating my client without having him to click on a link each  time my server side code need to perform an authenticated call.
I cannot managed to find a way to do such a simple thing with the flickr API, so, if there is a smarter guy reading this, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this without requiring the user to authorize you by clicking a link on Flickr's site the first time, however, once they've authenticated once, you can store and re-use their auth token until they revoke your application's permission.